# 'Half-Close' figure of Data Communications and Networking, 5/e

Tags: computer-networks, communication-protocols, tcp

[image]

In the Figure 24.13 of Data Communications and Networking, 5/e the first **ACK** message from the server holds `y-1` in it's *Sequence no.* field. Note that the first **FIN** message from the client message had `y` in it's *Acknowledgement no.* field. So shouldn't the first **ACK** message from the server be holding `y` in it's *Sequence no.* field instead of holding `y-1`? Is the diagram faulty or is there a reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The `FIN` segment consumes 1 sequence number as it does not carry data. `ACK` does not consume a sequence number. The `FIN` segment is sent by the client process. The server process receives a `FIN` segment but **does not send a `FIN` segment as the connection is not closed**, since it is a half-close process. Server process send only an `ACK` segment to acknowledge receipt of `FIN` segment from the client. Hence, the sequence number decreases by 1 and becomes $y-1$.

Contrast this with the Three way handshaking, where the sequence number is $y$ because in that process, the server sends a `ACK` segment as it acknowledges receipt of `FIN` segment from the client *and* sends a FIN segment as it terminates the connection.